# Extract second IP address in expression

Tags: regex, ip

I wan to extract second IP address (value of `DST`) from the following expression using regex:

```
kernel: DROP IN=eth0 
OUT= MAC=80:8d:8b:83:85:d0:f2:fc:bc:88:3e:f3:08:00 
SRC=111.111.111.111 
DST=222.222.222.222 
LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=10520 DF PROTO=TCP 
SPT=43219 DPT=10051 SEQ=4284041495 ACK=0 WINDOW=14600 
RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A7F8A63E80000000001030306)
```

I used the following regex to extract `SRC`:

```
^.+?((?:\d+\.){3}\d+).+$
```

I am unable to figure out the expression needed to extract the second IP (`DST`)

Comment: Fixed the grammar, formatted code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeating what you've got twice like so would work

`^.+?((?:\d+.){3}\d+).*?((?:\d+.){3}\d+).+$`

But a better regex that would capture all of the IP addresses would be

`((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})`

It looks like you had tried to match the periods in the IP address, but you forgot to escape them.

It wasn't necessary, but `{1,3}` can be used instead of `+` to limit the number of times you match a number.

Comment: The problem I have is that I am using graylog and it only capture 1st match as result, so I need an expression that only matches IP after DST i.e., 222.222.222.222

Comment: Add `DST=` in front `DST=((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})`

Comment: You sir are savior, I was messing with this (DST=)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) and it was adding DST in my output. Thank you.